# How to get the highest number in a set data points for a subfield in a PivotTable?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

In the attached screenshot below, I'm using x to get the 12.50% of "Short" in "First Grade." However, I'm looking to expand on this to find the largest value in the "First Grade" field and return the name. In "First Grade" for example it would be "Tall".

```
Sub PivotTest()

    Dim pvt As PivotTable: Set pvt = Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    x = pvt.GetPivotData("Count Of Height", "Grade", "First Grade", "Height", pvt.PivotFields("First Grade").PivotItems(1)).Value

End Sub
```

PivotTable Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can fiddle around with the following but it gives you a shape to work with. Apologies for any typos as am free typing this in as unable to paste at present.

The `GetMaxInfo` sub calls the function `MaxHeightInfo`, which takes the `Grade` as an argument, and returns an array containing the height description where the max count was found e.g. "Tall", and the count value itself. These are accessed by the (0) and (1) indices after the function call.

The function `MaxHeightInfo` uses the `GetPivotData` function to retrieve information for the specified `Grade` and sets `maxCount` to the highest value it finds. It stores the height description where this value is found in the `maxHeight` variable.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetMaxInfo()

    Msgbox MaxHeightInfo("First Grade")(0)
    Msgbox MaxHeightInfo("First Grade")(1)

    Msgbox MaxHeightInfo("Second Grade")(0)
    Msgbox MaxHeightInfo("Second Grade")(1)

End Sub

Public Function MaxHeightInfo(ByVal myGrade As String) As Variant

    Dim myHeight()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'change as appropriate

    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

    myHeight = Array("Short","Average","Tall")

    Dim currHeight As Long
    Dim maxCount As Double
    Dim maxHeight As String

    maxCount = 0
    maxHeight = vbNullString

    Dim testVal As Double

    For currHeight = LBound(myHeight) To UBound(myHeight)

        testVal = pvt.GetPivotData("Count of Height"),"Grade", myGrade,"Height", myHeight(currHeight)).Value

        If testVal > maxCount Then
            maxCount = testVal
            maxHeight = myHeight(currHeight)
        End If

    Next currHeight

    MaxHeightInfo = Array(maxHeight, maxCount)
End Function
```

Comment: This is actually perfect! Thanks a ton. I was able to follow how it all works as well. One question I have is say that I didn't know all of the variables in myHeight. And if the data table is freeform, anyone can type anything. So how would I loop through "First Grade" to populate the myHeight array assuming it could be any number of different strings

Comment: Then you would need a way to read the list of distinct variables into the myHeight array. Alternatively, you could loop the column where the values are found in the pivottable source data adding to a dictionary (this would produce a distinct list) - you could then loop the dictionary keys instead of the array. Am happy to give you an example if you get stuck giving that a try.

Comment: Yeah I think I got it actually. you can just assign values using y in the below. I appreciate all the help!

    For Each pi In pvt.PivotFields("Height").PivotItems
        y = pi.Name
    Next pi

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a non VBA solution in a few steps: 
First switch the view of your pivot table from [image]

to

[image]

After that you can solve it with a max if and an index match with two criteria: 
In the example:

```
{=MAX(IF(H3:H8="First Grade";J3:J8))}
```

=> This array formula gives you the max height for the first grade. 
Then with a double criteria index Match you can search for the max height of the first Grade:

```
{=INDEX(H3:J8;MATCH(1;(H3:H8="First Grade")*(J3:J8=*Cell of the maxIf*);0);2)}
```

Or the whole formula together longer:

```
{=INDEX(H3:J8;MATCH(1;(H3:H8="First Grade")*(J3:J8=MAX(IF(H3:H8="First Grade";J3:J8)));0);2)}
```

Works great on my Excel. I guess one could adapt this easily to VBA, but wouldn't be the cleanest.

Comment: That's actually really helpful for just adding a column into the data table! thanks